# MATLAB generate combination from a string

Tags: string, matlab, permutation

I've a string like this "FBECGHD" and i need to use MATLAB and generate all the required possible permutations? In there a specific MATLAB function that does this task or should I define a custom MATLAB function that perform this task?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [perms](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/perms.html) function. A string in matlab is a list of characters, so it will permute them:

```
A = 'FBECGHD';
perms(A)
```

You can also store the output (e.g. `P = perms(A)`), and, if A is an N-character string, P is a N!-by-N array, where each row corresponds to a permutation.

If you are interested in unique permutations, you can use:

```
unique(perms(A), 'rows')
```

to remove duplicates (otherwise something like 'ABB' would give 6 results, instead of the 3 that you might expect).

Answer (score 0):

As Richante answered, `P = perms(A)` is very handy for this. You may also notice that `P` is of type `char` and it's not convenient to subset/select individual permutation. Below worked for me:

```
str = 'FBECGHD';
A = perms(str);
B = cellstr(reshape(A,7,[])');
C = unique(B);
```

It also appears that `unique(A, 'rows')` is not removing duplicate values:

```
>> A=[11, 11];
>> unique(A, 'rows')
ans =

    11    11
```

However, `unique(A)` would:

```
>> unique(A)

ans =

    11
```

I am not a matlab pro by any means and I didn't investigate this exhaustively but at least in some cases it appears that `reshape` is not what you want. Notice that below gives `999` and `191` as permutations of `199` which isn't true. The reshape function as written appears to operate "column-wise" on `A`:

```
>> str = '199';
A = perms(str);
B = cellstr(reshape(A,3,[])');
C = unique(B);
>> C

C = 

    '191'
    '199'
    '911'
    '919'
    '999'
```

Below does not produce `999` or `191`:

```
B = {};
index = 1;
while true
    try
        substring = A(index,:);
        B{index}=substring;
        index = index + 1;
    catch
        break
    end
end
C = unique(B)

C = 

    '199'    '919'    '991'
```